# parse complex json in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

i have this json:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"john"},{"id":"2","name":"jack"},{"id":"3","name":"terry"}]
```

how i can parse this? i have to use a loop for extracting each group? for simple jsons  i use this code:

```
    public static String parseJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {

    try {

         JSONObject  json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

           // get name & id here
         String  name = json.getString("name");
         String  id =  json.getString("id");

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}
```

but now i have to parse my new json. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
public static String parseJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {

try {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);

    for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {
        JSONObject  json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

        // get name & id here
        String  name = json.getString("name");
        String  id =  json.getString("id");
    } 



} catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

return name;
}
```

Of course you should return an array of names or whatever you want..

Answer (score 2):

This is meant to be parsed by a **JSONArray**, and then each "record" is a **JSONObject**.

You can loop on the array and then retrieve the JSON String of each record with the [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString%28int%29) method. Then use this string to build a **JSONObject**, and just extract values like you do now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
public static void parseJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {

    try {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);     
        if(jsonArray != null){
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String  name = json.getString("name");
                String  id =  json.getString("id"); 
                //Store strings data or use it
            }
        }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You need to modify the loop to store or use the data.

Hope it helps.