# Android JSON parsing with a global JSON tag

Tags: android, json, parsing, tags

I am working on an Android project and my json strings are a bit strange, all of the tutorials are showing that I need to parse an JSONArray but my JSON has no array name.
Heres an example json url. (my understanding says that there needs to be something like "article" before the [

```
 [
 ///Something should be here
 {
    "id": 15483,
    "title": "Bilbo Baggins is Cool",
    "permalink": "http://example.com/2012/12/03/",
     "content": "Hello World",
    "date": "2012-12-03 00:04:08",
    "author": "Bilbo Baggins",
    "thumbnail": "http://example.com/wp-        content/uploads/2012/12/DSC02971.jpg",
    "categories": [
        "News"
    ],
    "tags": [
        "LOTR",
        "One Ring",
        "Patch",
        "Police Department"
    ]
}
]
```

Like this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
They have a tag at the beginning called "contacts" which lets him use a JSONArray to loop through all the contents and get the tags...
I am lost.
How can I parse this data? the tutorial code would not work as I cannot pull an array(as least i think).

Comment: The array has to have a name, if not..then it is a JSON object. The name should be before the first square bracket. Paste your url here and see if displays the complete content http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel

Comment: It looks like its just an JSON object then. Is there anything I can do to be able to parse individual objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 I am lost
```

First of all,I would like to tell you that in the example of androidhive,the `root` element of jsonstring is the `jsonobject` and the `root` element of jsonstring which you posted as question is the `jsonarray`.
Second of all,It's not necessary to always have a name at the beginning of array to consume it and extract data from it.but yes,it surely requires in complex cases and it is **good practice** too.

```
How can I parse this data?
```

the root element is different,so you need to change the way of consuming the data,

in example of androidhive,

```
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); //look at the left side of assignment operator.here result is being consumed in JSONObject

try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
    contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

    // looping through All Contacts
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

        // Phone number is agin JSON Object
        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the jsonstring which you posted as question can be consumed in JSONArray,

```
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); //look at the left side of assignment operator.here result is being consumed in JSONArray

try {
    // looping through All data
    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each item in variable
        String id = c.getString("id");
        String title= c.getString("title");
        String permalink= c.getString("permalink");
        String content= c.getString("content");

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But can't you not switch type from JSONObject to JSONArray? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I fixed it by changing the return type of the parsing class to a JSONArray, I'll see if this works!

Comment: It worked!!!!!! Thank you so much I just changed the parsing class to JSONArray as return object and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552123/parse-complex-json-in-android/14552221#14552221) post, it seems that you have a similar JSONArray.. you can simply use:

```
JSONArray yourArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
// do the rest of the parsing by looping through the JSONArray
```